# I need to determine Total Memory and Disk within Bash

Tags: bash, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm currently trying to get the total disk and total memory of the machine. This task needs to be done in bash. My output should look like this:

```
---
Total disk: {VALUE}G
Total memory: {VALUE}MB
---
```

I wrote the following code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
TotalDisk=`(df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "%d",$2}')`
TotalMemory=$(free -m | awk 'NR==2 {printf "%d",$2}');
echo "---
Total disk : ${TotalDisk}G
Total memory : ${TotalMemory}MB
---"
```

And I want use it as refer log file, and sent alert email when the total disk space is under certain amount

Comment: Works for me. What do you mean by "not accepted"? Do you get any errors? If so, please [edit] your question and include the errors. See also [ask].

Answer (score 2):

### edited

use double quotes `"` when printing the result (`echo $TOTAL_DISK` and `echo $TOTAL_MEM`)

`df` and `free` have a flag `total` that gives you the total

```sh
#!/bin/bash
TOTAL_DISK=`df -h --total | awk 'END{print $2}'`
TOTAL_MEM=`free --total --mega| awk 'END{print $2"MB"}'`

echo '---'
echo "Total disk: $TOTAL_DISK"
echo "Total disk: $TOTAL_MEM"
echo '---'
```

Comment: i try the statemen TOTAL_DISK=`df -h --total | awk 'END{print $2}'` for total disk and TOTAL_DISK=$(df -H --total |awk 'END {printf "%d",$2}')  but the system show output is incorrect

Comment: i try the statemen TOTAL_MEM=`free --total --mega| awk 'END{print $2"MB"}'` and TotalMemory=$(free --si -t --mega | awk 'END {print $2}'); but the system show output is incorrect

Comment: you need to include the backticks ` this is a command substitution which means the command inside the backticks will be run.
another option is to replace backticks with parentheses

Comment: i try as well in both case with $ and ` ` for bash command, in both case they give the output but it does get the correct answer for code question